# Redirect ALL requests to host IP

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache

I have a honeypot running on AP so if anyone connects and try's to browse it will redirect to the root page. I am using dnsmasq to do this with the following entry

```
log-facility=/var/log/dnsmasq.log
address=/#/10.0.0.1
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=10.0.0.10,10.0.0.250,12h
no-resolv
log-queries
```

This works fine if someone were to go to `http://example.com` but if they try `http://example.com/somerandompage.html` I get a `404` error or if they try `https://example.com` it just times out.

What would be the best method to redirect everything to `http://serverip/index.html` while still allowing `http://serverip/someOtherPage?with=options.html` with a preference for .htaccess solution.

Comment: "AP" == Apache?

Comment: Sorry, Access point

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to use .htaccess? You presumably have full control of your server? So, a server config solution would be preferable. What does dnsmasq do exactly? (Where does it sit in the network layer?) Just a bit surprised that if it's handling DNS then why it doesn't handle `http://example.com/somerandompage.html` at the same time as `http://example.com`?

Answer (score 1):

> if they try `http://example.com/somerandompage.html` I get a 404 error

To redirect all requests to `example.com` (non-HTTPS) back to the `serverip/index.html` in .htaccess (or perferably in your server config):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://serverip/index.html [R=301,L]
```

This assumes your site is only accessible over `example.com`. If you also have the `www` subdomain then you would need to modify the condition to read:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
```

This will also redirect `http://example.com` or does dnsmasq kick in before this?

> if they try `https://example.com` it just times out.

You will only be able to resolve this by making your site accessible over HTTPS. ie. by installing a security certificate.

> I have a honeypot...

If by "honeypot" you mean you are logging and blocking IPs/users that access the domain, then redirecting in .htaccess might skip this out (depending on when dnsmasq runs?). You could perhaps redirect to `http://example.com` instead?